# Как на баше сразу перейти в директорию, в которую копируем файл

Tags: linux, bash

Очень часто приходится копировать файлы в папки с большой вложенностью. 
Как после копирования можно было бы сразу перейти в папку, в которую копируем? Возможно, какой-то ключ?

Пример:

```
cp file1 /home/testuser/dir1/testdir/cp_outd/35/testdir64/33/
```

Answer (score 4):

У `cp` нет нужной опции. Можно прописать `alias` в `.bashrc`

```
alias cpandcd='cp $1 $2; cd $2'
```

Если нужно копировать много файлов, нужно будет немного извратиться с последним аргументом, но все решаемо.

Да, c `alias` что-то не сработало. Там хитро с аргументами на самом деле. Так работает проверил:

```
function cpandcd {
    cp $1 $2
    cd $2
}
```

Это "цитата" из моего `.bashrc`

Учитывая последний ответ, видимо сработает так (для любого числа файлов)

```
cpandcd () {
    cp $@ && cd $_
}
```

Проверил, работает `cpandcd file1 file2 ... path/`

Comment: По вашему методу получается.  
 `cpandcd 123 Dir/test2
cp: missing file operand
Try 'cp --help' for more information.
bash: cd: 123: Not a directory`

Comment: С alias действительно ничего не выйдет, т.к. видимо нет способа два раза использовать аргументы строки, он просто их подставляет после строки в кавычках.

Answer (score 4):

всё очень просто

```
cp file /path
cd $_
```

http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Special_Parameters_and_Variables

Answer (score 2):

по умолчанию последний аргумент предыдущей команды можно подставить, нажав любую из комбинаций:

- <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>
- <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>_</kbd>
- <kbd>esc</kbd> затем <kbd>.</kbd>
- <kbd>esc</kbd> затем <kbd>_</kbd>

повторное нажатие любой из этих комбинаций приведёт к подстановке последнего аргумента *предыдущей* команды, и т.д.

---

к примеру, вы только что выполнили какую-нибудь команду:

```
$ прогамма1 аргумент1 аргумент2 аргумент3
```

после этого набираете, например, <kbd>программа2</kbd>, затем пробел, затем <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> и получаете в командной строке такую картину:

```
$ программа2 аргумент3
```

---

всё это работает не только в программе *gnu/bash*, но и в любой программе, использующей библиотеку [*gnu/readline*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Readline) для взаимодействия с пользователями.

для конфигурирования поведения можно использовать файл `~/.inputrc`.

справку можно почитать [онлайн](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html#Documentation) или командами `man readline` и `man history`.

Comment: не знал про теги `<kbd>`. Круто, спасибо! : )